# Testing custom validation method with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, rspec, factory-bot

I try to test validation method that check times overlap for activities.

There are three factories(two of them inherit from activity).

Factories:

activities.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :activity do
      name 'Fit Girls'
      description { Faker::Lorem.sentence(3, true, 4) }
      active true
      day_of_week 'Thusday'
      start_on '12:00'
      end_on '13:00'
      pool_zone 'B'
      max_people { Faker::Number.number(2) }
      association :person, factory: :trainer

   factory :first do
     name 'Swim Cycle'
     description 'Activity with water bicycles.'
     active true
     day_of_week 'Thusday'
     start_on '11:30'
     end_on '12:30'
  end

   factory :second do
     name 'Aqua Crossfit'
     description 'Water crossfit for evereyone.'
     active true
     day_of_week 'Thusday'
     start_on '12:40'
     end_on '13:40'
     pool_zone 'C'
     max_people '30'
   end
   end
 end
```

Activities overlaps when are on same day_of_week(activity.day_of_week == first.day_of_week), on same pool_zone(activity.pool_zone == first.pool_zone) and times overlaps.

Validation method:

```
  def not_overlapping_activity
    overlapping_activity = Activity.where(day_of_week: day_of_week)
                                   .where(pool_zone: pool_zone)

    activities = Activity.where(id: id)
    if activities.blank?
      overlapping_activity.each do |oa|
        if (start_on...end_on).overlaps?(oa.start_on...oa.end_on)
          errors.add(:base, "In this time and pool_zone is another activity.")
        end
      end
    else
      overlapping_activity.where('id != :id', id: id).each do |oa|
        if (start_on...end_on).overlaps?(oa.start_on...oa.end_on)
          errors.add(:base, "In this time and pool_zone is another activity.")
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

I wrote rspec test, but unfortunatelly invalid checks.

```
describe Activity, 'methods' do
  subject { Activity }
 describe '#not_overlapping_activity' do
    let(:activity) { create(:activity) }
    let(:first) { create(:first) }

      it 'should have a valid factory' do
        expect(create(:activity).errors).to be_empty
      end
      it 'should have a valid factory' do
        expect(create(:first).errors).to be_empty
      end

    context 'when day_of_week, pool_zone are same and times overlap' do
      it 'raises an error that times overlap' do
        expect(activity.valid?).to be_truthy
        expect(first.valid?).to be_falsey
        expect(first.errors[:base].size).to eq 1
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Return:

```
Failure/Error: expect(first.valid?).to be_falsey

       expected: falsey value
            got: true
```

I can't understand why it got true. First create(:activity) should be right, but next shouldn't be executed(overlapping).
I tried add `expect(activity.valid?).to be truthy` before `expect(first.valid?...`, but throws another error `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid`. Could someone repair my test? I'm newbie with creation tests using RSpec.

UPDATE:
Solution for my problem is not create :first in test but build.
`let(:first) { build(:first) }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line on its own

```
let(:activity) { create(:activity) }
```

doesn't create an activity. It only creates an activity, when `activity` is actually called. Therefore you must call `activity` somewhere before running your test.

There are several ways to do so, for example a before block:

```
before { activity }
```

or you could use `let!` instead of just `let`.

Comment: You have right. It makes sense, but like I mentioned first.valid? returns `RecordInvalid`. Do you know what can be cause?

Comment: A validation fails when you create the `first` factory object. Check the validations you've defined in `activity.rb`.

Comment: @Arun Factory girl's create uses save! so that exception shows your validation is firing

Comment: Are you sure that your factory returns valid instances? I mean do you have tests that test reach factory in isolation (Something like `except(build(:activity)).to be_valid` or `except(create(:activity).errors).to be_empty`)?

Comment: @spickermann I checked, activity and have valid factory. Before I tested validation method manually and works good. Now still show that `let(:first) { create(:first) } - InvalidRecord `

Comment: Please investigate why the record in invalid. `let(:first) { build(:first).tap { |e| p e.valid?; p e.errors } }` might help...

Comment: Ok, I know why it's not work, cause was validation that block(times overlap) creation. To pass test I have to let(:activity) create but let(:first) build.